# can tee redirect a fifo to stdout in c programming?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fifo

I want to redirect a fifo to stdout and 
I read the doc http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/tee.2.html

It says `tee(int fd_in, int fd_out,...)`

but when I throw a fifo fd to the 1st arguments, it says invalid error.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main() {
    int num = 0, fd;
    char fifo[] = "/tmp/tmpfifo";

    fd = open(fifo, O_RDONLY, 0644);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    num = tee(fd, STDOUT_FILENO, INT_MAX, SPLICE_F_NONBLOCK);
    if (num < 0) {
        perror("tee");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(stderr,"%d\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

The console shows: tee:invalid arguments.
The 1st argu should be stdin?

Comment: I think you want the [`dup2`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) function.

Comment: By the way, are you sure about the flags passed to `open`? Shouldn't it be only `O_RDONLY` or `O_WRONLY`? Is your program supposed to communicate with itself? How did you create the FIFO?

Comment: Does that works if I still use tee() syscall?

Comment: With your edit, is the purpose to automatically pipe all you read from the FIFO to `stdout`? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve?

Comment: You should not open a fifo for both reading and writing, you must separate the calls... `tee` is intended to work with fifos, from the doc `EINVAL fd_in or fd_out does not refer to a pipe; or fd_in and fd_out refer to the same pipe.`. Is stdout a fifo?

Comment: I fix the RDWR to RDONLY, it doesn't work again.
If I follow the examples below the doc, it works. The example put STDIN and STDOUT to the first two argus.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I should make STDOUT_FILENO a pipe like below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `tee()`'s man pages:

> tee() duplicates up to len bytes of data from the pipe referred to by
>          the file descriptor fd_in to the pipe referred to by the file
>          descriptor fd_out.

So, both *file descriptors* must refer to pipes.

In your call to `tee()`:

```
tee(fd, STDOUT_FILENO, INT_MAX, SPLICE_F_NONBLOCK);
```

`fd` is a fifo, which is in turn a pipe, but `STDOUT_FILENO` may not refer to a pipe.

`STDIN_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO` are not necessarily pipes.

---

If you want `STDOUT_FILENO` to refer to a pipe, you can run your program at the shell's command line in the following way:

```
yourProgram | cat
```

Comment: fifo isn't a pipe?

Comment: @code_worker but `STDOUT_FILENO` is not necessarily a pipe.

Comment: I know. But I open a fifo, and the fifo is a pipe. so I think put the fifo to the 1st argu should be correct, right?

Comment: @code_worker you can execute your program as `./myProgram | cat`, then `STOUT_FILENO` refers to a pipe.

Comment: Actually the shell creates the pipe, your program just inherit (as a child process) a file descriptor which corresponds to that pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `stdout` is a pipe.

```
rm -f /tmp/tmpfifo
mkfifo /tmp/tmpfifo
echo hello world > /tmp/tmpfifo & 
./a.out | cat #ensure that the program's stdout is a pipe
```

(where `a.out` is your program) works for me.

Comment: It works. I thought STDOUT_FILENO  will print on console originally.